# How to resume a "paused" application after an out of memory situation?

Tags: memory, activity-monitor

Occasionally - even with abundant care - my 16GB MBPro runs out of application memory and the dreaded "No more application memory available" dialog appears.

Fortunately we are still able to access `Activity Monitor`:  and the first thing I do is kill the web browsers that tend to accumulate large amounts of memory over time.

Less fortunate is that - even after verifying that the `Memory Used` + `Swap Memory` are less than 10GB combined, it is *still* not possible to resurrect the ***Paused*** applications.

[image]

If it were not possible to resuscitate the paused apps - then what good is this notification?  Are we compelled to simply kill the apps ourselves?  Given there is *now* sufficient memory for any of the remaining open apps to continue then why are they *still* unable to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in front of my mac right now, but basic steps would be:

1. Open the Terminal application: just type `Terminal` into Spotlight
2. List the running processes : `ps -ax`
3. Find the process you want to unpause. You need its PID *Process Id
4. To unpause, strangely enough you use the "Kill" command on the process with the CONT flag: `kill -CONT [app_pid]` **dont forget the -CONT** as otherwise you will kill it instead of unpausing. In your example that'd be`kill -Cont 69971`

You can get the pid from the Activity Monitor if you have that column showing

Comment: you totally missed the CONT flag in the kill command didnt you ...

Comment: Yes I did: apologies. A  suggestion would be to put that in bold at the top of the post: I will not be the only one to miss that detail.

Comment: trying it out now.  Seems to have worked. That's neat.

Comment: Important note: The `kill` command doesn't kill, its purpose is to send a signal to a process The thing is that the default signal if none is specified does kill the process.